# Auto login in dropbox folder with OAuth

Tags: ios, oauth, dropbox-api

Only for internal use i need to display the content of our dropbox folder in a tableview inside our app without show for the login screen and handle back the authentication url.
In all the example i've found only the reference to

```
#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>

DBSession *dbSession = [[DBSession alloc]
  initWithAppKey:@"INSERT_APP_KEY"
  appSecret:@"INSERT_APP_SECRET"
  root:INSERT_ACCESS_TYPE]; // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
```

and after tha the authentication is handle as url call back from the web page of dropbox.

but there is a way of handle the different part to the autenticantion and keep them in code?

May be could be easily handle with direct api call ?

In the dropbox "app console" i've found a "Generated access token" but i'm not understand how to use.

Thanks for your help and for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The Dropbox API was designed with the intention that each user would link their own Dropbox account, in order to interact with their own files. However, it is technically possible to connect to just one account. The SDKs don't offer explicit support for it and we don't recommend doing so, for various technical and security reasons.

However if you did want to go this route, instead of kicking off the authorization flow, you would manually use an existing access token for your app. (Just be careful not to revoke it, e.g. via https://www.dropbox.com/account/security .) In the iOS Core SDK you'd need to use:

```
- (void)updateAccessToken:(NSString *)token accessTokenSecret:(NSString *)secret forUserId:(NSString *)userId;
```

Again though, this isn't a good idea. Since this would be a client-side app, any malicious user of your app could extract the access token and use it to bypass any access restrictions your app attempted to enforce. For example, they could access content they shouldn't or add or replace content with a malicious payload that other users would access.

Answer (score -1):

Unless Dropbox changed their API recently, the user must manually supply a username / password.  This can be done by popping out to the Dropbox app or using a Dropbox web view.  You can not programmatically supply a default username / password.

Comment: Thank bbarnhart for your answer i not manually supply user/password i want to allow access based on OAuth flow but without show to the user the login or authorized app page. Thanks